# Ошибка при установки модуля discord на python3.9

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\призрак коммунизма\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\призрак коммунизма\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\s
ite-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\92A4~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp04xrlxoa'
       cwd: C:\Users\ПРИЗРАК КОММУНИЗМА\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-10_4ynan\multidict
  Complete output (42 lines):
  Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\dict.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\istr.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\iter.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\pair_list.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  copying multidict\_multilib\views.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\multidict\_multilib
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\призрак коммунизма\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\призрак коммунизма\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\s
ite-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\92A4~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbb9r3ugi'
       cwd: C:\Users\ПРИЗРАК КОММУНИЗМА\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-10_4ynan\yarl
  Complete output (37 lines):
  Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_url.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting_c.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------`введите сюда код`
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить Visual Studio Build Tools по этой [ссылке](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/7/5f7acaeb-8363-451f-9425-68a90f98b238/visualcppbuildtools_full.exe?fixForIE=.exe.)